# Using FireDAC with SQLite RETURNING Clause?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I found that SQLite supports a `RETURNING` clause for `INSERT INTO` to return values of auto generated fields.

Can those values be returned to `FireDAC` (say when using `FDConnection::SQLExec`) and if so how do you retrieve it using `FireDAC`?

TIA!!

Comment: Yes, certainly. Just open using `Open`, as you would do if it were a simple `select`.